# Issue with adding UL markup for LI

Tags: javascript, jquery

This sounds simple, and it should be, but it doesn't seem to be so cut and dry...

I have a list of `li` elements..

```
<li>Text here</li>
<li>Text here</li>
<li>Text here</li>
```

What I want to do is find the 1st one, add `<ul>` before it. Find the last one, add `</ul>`

It sounds simple but stay with me...

First I tried this:

```
$('li').each(function(i,obj) {
  var x = $(this);
  if(x.prev().prop('tagName')!=='LI') x.before('<ul>')    
  if(x.next().prop('tagName')!=='LI') x.after('</ul>')    
});
```

Which evolved into this:

```
$('li').each(function(i,obj) {
  var x = $(this);
  $.fn.outerHTML = function(){
    var x = $(this);
    x.wrap('<p/>')
    var html = x.parent().html();
    x.unwrap();
    return(html);
  }

  alert(x.outerHTML());
  if(x.prev().prop('tagName')!=='LI') x.html('<ul>'+x.outerHTML())    
  if(x.next().prop('tagName')!=='LI') x.html(x.outerHTML()+'</ul>')  

});
```

The 1st code places an empty `UL` before the 1st LI (closing tag and all)

The 2nd wraps only the 1st `LI`.

It goes down the list 1, 2, 3 and seems to report back properly... something (possibly jQuery) seems to be altering my code somewhere along the way. Can anyone shed some insight here?

Fiddle to fiddle with: http://jsfiddle.net/yr67N/

**Update:**
As you can see from the code, the `li`s must be grouped together. `wrapAll` won't work here.

Comment: I'd suggest that your first method is almost there. Having created that ul before them all keep a reference and then move all the following li into that ul.

Comment: Something like making an array of objects starting with the 1st, breaking on the condition next element is not `li`, then cloning the objects into `ul` and removing the originals? Why doesn't this code work since it essentially finds 1st and last of grouped `li`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ul,
    tname;
$('li').each(function(i, el){

    tname = $(el).prev().prop('tagName');

    if(String(tname) !== 'UL'){
        ul = $('<ul></ul>');
        $(el).before(ul[0]);
    }
       $(this).appendTo(ul);

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/729Ka/16/)

Comment: After some extensive testing, both JustinMs version and Quentins worked on the big 3 (FF, Chrome, IE). This one gets the vote simply because it's less code, avoids arrays, and Justin got 3 upvotes while this one only received one. Both great answers, thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried this on your fiddle and it appears to work:

```
var collectedLi = [];
$('li').each(function(){
    collectedLi.push(this);
    if(!$(this).next().is('li')){
        $(collectedLi).wrapAll('<ul/>');
        collectedLi = []
    }
});
```

For every li it will check if the next element is also an li, if not it will wrap the current collection in a ul and then empty the collection to continue the loop.

Just realized that the above code will also wrap already wrapped li tags,  here is a solution that will handle this:

```
var collectedLi = [];
$('li').each(function(){
    collectedLi.push(this);
    if(!$(this).next().is('li')){
        if(!$(this).parent().is('ul')){
            $(collectedLi).wrapAll('<ul/>');
        }
        collectedLi = []
    }
});
```

Comment: Copied the code to a fiddle, but it doesn't wrap anything. http://jsfiddle.net/yr67N/10/

Comment: +1'ed, my hardlearned lesson of the day: never try to `.before` or `.after` a ul

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$('li').wrapAll('<ul/>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yr67N/2/)

Comment: Strip the li of the dot and you are fine.

Comment: That doesn't sound like what I'm wanting.. sounds like that would wrap ALL `li` elements. I want it to wrap only those grouped together. Here's why: http://jsfiddle.net/yr67N/3/

Comment: @kcdwayne I can't find that in your question, maybe add it since this is the right answer for your question in it's current state.

Comment: @Marcel If you look at either code sample, its fairly apparent... nevertheless.

Comment: How is it 'apparent'? You show three `<li>` elements, unwrapped and without context. Show *representative* HTML, and show the desired output/end-result that should be generated. As it is this answers your question, if you update your question to reproduce your actual problem, you'll get far more useful answers.